# Identifying Structure based off 1H-NMR & Mass Spectroscopy Data

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy, mass-spectrometry

I have almost the whole night trying to identify this structure with no avail as there is always one part that does not fit. The determined formula for this structure was $\ce{C13H17BrO}$ from the $m/z=268$ (M-100%), $m/z=269$ (M+1-14.7%), and $m/z=270$ (M+2-98.6%).

The $\ce{^1H}$-NMR data is as follows with integration in parentheses:

a. $\pu{7.30-7.27 ppm}$: multiplet (5) - arene with 5 hydrogens

b. $\pu{3.20 ppm}$: singlet (2) - R-**CH2**-Br attached to tetra-substituted carbon?

c. $\pu{2.45 ppm}$: triplet (2) - R-CH2-**CH2**-CO-CH3

d. $\pu{2.17 ppm}$: singlet (3) - R-CH2-CO-**CH3**

e. $\pu{1.68 ppm}$: sextet (2) - R-CH2-**CH2**-CH3

f. $\pu{0.90 ppm}$: triplet (3) - R-CH2-**CH3**

And this is the structure I come up with:

[image: ![enter image description here]

which is the only structure that fits all the hydrogen integrations, but does not support the chemical shift at all.

I believe this is part of the molecule

[image]

because it takes care of shifts d,c,e,f. However, it is impossible to attach that structure to the remaining Arene, CH2-Br, and tetra substituted carbon. Actually spent over 6 hours on this problem and I'm losing my mind please help me.

Comment: You are just concerned with the shift of 2.45 right? I think your proposed structure does take care of that shift. The inductive effect of the carbonyl and the bromine atom may just be sufficient to cause such a deshielding effect.

Comment: c. 2.45 ppm triplet (2)- R-CH2-**CH2**-CO-CH3? $$$$
Did you mean R-**CH2**-CH2-CH3?

Comment: Did you deduce molecular formula by MS data or it is given? If so, I believe you may need  additional decimal point on parent peak and others to do so. For example, ChemDraw is given M+1 peak as 14.1%  instead of 14.7% on your data for $\ce{^{79}Br}$ containing peak.

Comment: Also, the part of molecule you are suggesting is a complete molecule. So, it can't be a part.

Comment: TanYongBoon Yeah, the shift at 2.45 doesn't really make sense according to this chart that I was given since a shift a 2.40 correlates to the CH2 attached to a carbonyl, but I too think its somewhat plausible that the 2.45 shift could be cause by deshielding thanks!. Karsten According to my proposed structure it is Ch2-ch2-ch3, but the ppm shift and splitting is more in line with the ch2 attached to a carbonyl, sorry I might have worded it strangely. Mathew I determined the formula from (M+1)/13 and 1:1 ratio of M to M+2 for 79 Bromine, but it didn't match up to the exact values!